# Обновление переменной при каждом вызове метода. Объясните тонкости инициализации переменных при объявлении

Tags: c#

Есть `RichTextBox`, в который введен произвольный текст. При нажатии комбинации клавиш `alt+Right` хочу поочередно выделять каждое слово в тексте (последовательность символов от пробела до пробела). Добавил для этого `KeyEventHandler`, в котором прописал:

```
    private void hotKeys(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) {
                if (richTextBox.Focused)
                {
                    int pos = Regex.Match(richTextBox.Text, @"\s+").Index;
                    richTextBox.SelectionLength = pos;
                }
            }
        }
```

Но комбинация клавиш работает некорректно: запоминает в pos длину первого слова в тесте и далее подставляет его везде. Как я понял данное регулярное выражение ищет в тексте любое количество пробелов начиная с текущей позиции курсора. (Для начала текста нужно указать `^`), а значит переменная `pos` просто не обновляется.

1. Почему `pos` не обновляла значение?
2. Нет ли в коде утечки памяти, ведь я создаю pos каждый раз при нажатии комбинации клавиш?

Comment: Никакой разницы между этими вариантами нет. Утечки памяти там тоже нет.

Comment: @Igor Да, вы правы, еще раз проверил... Почему не обновляется  значение переменной? Курсор же находится в новой позиции при повторном вызове метода

Comment: Что значит "не обновляется". Вы определяете ее значение совершенно независимо от позиции курсора. Если текст в `richTextBox` не меняется, то `pos` всегда будет присваиваться одно и то же значение.

Comment: С чего вы взяли про "начиная с текущей позиции курсора"? В коде ничего нет про позицию курсора.

Comment: И да, в C# стандартные типы данных (managed) корректно удаляются из памяти при выходе из блока `{...}`, утечка памяти может быть только на unmanaged ресурсах.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я делаю richTextBox.SelectionLength = pos , что выделяет текст,  так? Далее я нажимаю стрелку влево и курсор оказывается после выделенного слова в тексте. Взял я это потому, что для начала текста в регулярных выражениях есть ^

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Вы путаете понятия. Указания где в тексте что-то искать для регулярок (например, с начала текста) не имеют никакого отношения к позиции курсора в элементе GUI. Вы же берёте просто весь текст из контрола: `richTextBox.Text`

Comment: Это Winforms? Добавьте тег `winforms` к вопросу тогда.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
   int pos = 0;
   private void hotKeys(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) {
            if (richTextBox.Focused)
            {
                pos += Regex.Match(richTextBox.Text.Substring(pos), @"\s+").Index;
                richTextBox.SelectionLength = pos;
            } else pos = 0;
        } 
    }
```

Правильно будет устанавливать позицию когда текс бокс получит фокус

Comment: Не скомпилируется.

Comment: И Какая же ошибка?

Comment: Например - "использование неинициализированной локальной переменной `pos`".

Comment: Ну переменную я тут не объявляю. Я просто показал как изменить код

Comment: Код не скомпилируется.

Comment: А так  думаю может получиться